# Is there any way to disable the iPhone 5's passcode functionality while connected to Xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone

It don't know if a solution exists or not but I couldn't find anything on Google or Ask Different, so here goes:

I have an iPhone 5 with iOS 6 and when developing and testing I always have to enter a passcode to test my applications. Is there *any* way to make sure I dont enter the passcode every time when it's connected to Xcode 4.5.

I know that I can disable it during development, etc... but that defeats the purpose of phone security if you need to rush out quickly for work, etc...

It would be great if anyone has the solution for this so it just works!

Comment: Maybe you could look into a timeout for requiring the passcode? I personally set it to 5 mins so I can go back and forth to my iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, there's no way to disable the passcode lock solely when you're connected to your system and using Xcode.

> I know i can disable it during development etc... but it defeats the
>   purpose of phone security when you need to rush out quickly for work
>   etc.....

As much as it defeats the purpose of security to disable the passcode, having functionality to selectively disable it when using Xcode would be an even *bigger* security issue.

Comment: Surely apple should be able to validate when device is connected to registerd xcode profile and registered user when plugging in that way this eliminates the use of disabling passcode.

Comment: since there is no option like this exist i will take this as correct answer and will increase timeout to 5mins